# Running a C/C++ console application inside a C# windowed one?

Tags: c#, console

Right now, I want to develop a simple application, so I decided that the fastest way to code would be C#.NET, but right now, I'm having a hard time to implement one of the features I need.

What I'm trying to do, is to run a C/C++ console application inside the window of my C# application, like in Unreal Frontend with the little addition of to way communication, so that I can give the console application input for *scanf() and std::sin*. And what control should I user to display and get the data?

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start the C++ process using the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), and use [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) and [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) to pass data back and forth.

Comment: Hi,did this work? as I have used this method and it does not work

Comment: Did the output from the C++ exe show in the C# solution (i.e. in a panel). I ask as I have used this example, got it to run, but the output from the C++ console is not showing in the C# application. This works fine with a regular C# exe.

Comment: @Funky: You have to have a way to redirect from the stream to the panel.  This is doable, but a bit tricky, as there's no events on stream.  It's definitely possible - look at the Output window in Visual Studio - that's how it's done ;)